# Looking for some help with a question on proofs, whether these roots are irrational

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

if a and b are positive integers, and a is not equal to b, and neither a nor b is a perfect square,

then roota multiplied by rootb is irrational.

how would I go about this?

Comment: It's not true. Take for instance $a=2,b=8$.

Comment: Did you try a few small examples to get some insight into how $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ acts?